# Save image data URI at a dimension size in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which saves a screenshot of my canvas:

```
var currentGameContainer = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
var dataImageURL = currentGameContainer[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
```

But this saves the whole canvas at it's full size. Is there a way I can save it to 200px x 300px? I want to do this as it saves it too large.

Comment: How'd you go with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy its contents to a new, smaller, temporary canvas, using [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage). The resampling is automatic if you use all the parameters. Get your image from the temporary canvas then delete that canvas. It never needs to be part of the DOM.